# Keep Getting Error 17048 Firebase SMS Token Mismatch

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-cloud-messaging

I keep getting 17048: Token Mismatch with no other info when trying to send a OTP to my phone number with Firebase Auth. Steps I've tried to resolve this:

1. Regenerated my APN key in the developer portal and reuploaded this to Firebase
2. Ensured that these two functions are in my AppDelegate:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
          let firebaseAuth = Auth.auth()
            firebaseAuth.setAPNSToken(deviceToken, type: AuthAPNSTokenType.unknown)
    
      }
    
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
          let firebaseAuth = Auth.auth()
          if (firebaseAuth.canHandleNotification(userInfo)){
              print(userInfo)
              return
          }
      }
```

3. Checked my bundle and team Ids

SMS was working for my app until I got a new mac. Once I started building the app on my new device I started to get this issue. Any help would be great, thanks!